# Phing avoids Selenium browser settings in PHPUnit configuration

Tags: selenium, phpunit, phing

I setup up a phing project with two targets: the first runs `phpunit` test cases that includes selenium server as well and the second generates phpunit test reports using `phpunitreport` task.

phpunit task is configured to use an external configuration file called "`phpunit-config.xml`". This config XML file has a `<selenium />` tag where two browsers are defined. This browser settings are not being processed therefore I am getting an exception from Selenium RC Server: "`Browser not supported:`" - please note the empty browser name here.

If I run phpunit directly from command line with the same configuraiton XML file everything works as expected.

phing-build.xml:

```
<project name="test-and-report" default="gen-report" basedir=".">

<target name="gen-report" depends="run-tests" >
    <phpunitreport infile="report-junit.xml" format="frames" todir="report-phing" styledir="xsl/">
    </phpunitreport>
</target>

<target name="run-tests">
    <phpunit configuration="phpunit-config.xml">
        <formatter type="xml" outfile="report-junit.xml"></formatter>
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="functional">
                <include name="functional/**/*Test.php" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </phpunit>
</target>
```

phpunit-config.xml:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
    colors="false"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    stopOnFailure="false">

<selenium>
    <browser name="Internet Explorer" browser="*iexplore" />
    <browser name="Firefox" browser="*firefox" />
</selenium>

</phpunit>
```

Not working scenario:

```
phing -buildfile phing-build.xml
```

Working scenario:

```
phpunit --configuration phpunit-config.xml functional\
```

In the not working scenario I'm getting the following error message from Selenium RC server:

```
16:31:43.746 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[, http://localhost:8001 /index-test.php/] on session null
16:31:43.746 INFO - creating new remote session
16:31:43.746 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: java.lang.RuntimeException: Browser not supported:
(Did you forget to add a *?)

Supported browsers include:
 *firefox
 *mock
 *firefoxproxy
 <cutted here>
```

Any suggestions?

I have also raised a ticket for this: http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/983

Answer (score 0):

For inquiring minds, the discussion in the ticket resolves this question:

> Thanks for the report! Our phpunit task does not yet support the
>    tag, so I'm going to mark this as an enhancement, not a
>   defect :)